# Python imaplib returns UIDs in the list name, not list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail, imap

Not sure if this counts as me answering my own question as it's more of a workaround that I'd like some clarity on.

As a part of a system I'm building, I fetch emails from an email account using GMail's IMAP extensions, matching a certain subject and being newer than a day old. This script runs every minute. Throughout the past week this account has received hundreds of emails that fit the search criteria, and yet every time it runs it keeps finding the same UIDs and emails. I traced this to be because the actual UIDs I want are not in the list values, but part of the list "name" of sorts? See below:

[image: imaplib oddity]

In my original script, as in many other code samples available on this site and everywhere else Python's imaplib is demonstrated, I was grabbing the IDs from data[0]. But that list has duplicate and seemingly nonsensical values, since they are the same for every time the program runs (or at least similar enough that the program does not in fact get the latest emails returned by the search).

The first [0] is the first (and only) list in the object, but its contents are irrelevant. The tooltip and greyed bytestring is what I'm looking for. Am I missing something in my understanding of how imaplib works and how I should be extracting the IDs? My colleague and I are puzzled by this, but we came up with a workaround that I'm not too comfortable with:

```
type, data = mail.uid('search', None, r'X-GM-RAW "subject:\"my-subject\" and newer_than:1d"')

#Turn the list into a string list
id_list = str(data).split(" ")

#Removes erroneous b' and '] from the first and last list items
id_list[0] = id_list[0][3:]
id_list[-1] = id_list[-1][:len(id_list[-1])-2]

#Whatever you want to do with the mails goes here
```

Did I read the docs and examples incorrectly or is there some other issue at play here?

Comment: Yeah, it's a list of ascii encoded numbers.  You want something like [int(x) for x in uids.split()]

Comment: The expansion you're seeing is the byte string being treated as a list of integers: eg, the ascii values of '3', '9', '3', ' '....